# what tables and how many rows are affected by the actions in a single wal file

Tags: postgresql, wal, postgresql-15

We use postgresql as a database. For the backup part, we store full cluster backups and wal files to allow point in time restoration of our database.

Our wal files take up quite a bit of space when compared to our full backups, so we would like to inspect the content of our wal files, and more precisely be able to see what tables contribute the most to the volume of our wal files.

**Question**

Is there a way to inspect what tables/relations are targeted by the actions stored in a specific wal file ? and how many rows or records are affected ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pg_waldump` is the tool you'd want to use to inspect the contents of a WAL file.  Basically, you can look to see which DML and DDL statements (along with other events) were captured into the WAL file.

One example is below:

```
-bash-4.2$ pgbench -i
dropping old tables...
creating tables...
generating data (client-side)...
100000 of 100000 tuples (100%) done (elapsed 0.27 s, remaining 0.00 s)
vacuuming...
creating primary keys...
done in 0.77 s (drop tables 0.03 s, create tables 0.04 s, client-side generate 0.34 s, vacuum 0.21 s, primary keys 0.15 s).
-bash-4.2$ psql -c "select * from pg_class where relname= 'pgbench_accounts'"
  oid  |     relname      | relnamespace | reltype | reloftype | relowner | relam | relfilenode | reltablespace | relpages | reltuples | relallvisible | reltoastrelid | relhasindex | relisshared | relpersistence | relkind | relnatts | relch
ecks | relhasrules | relhastriggers | relhassubclass | relrowsecurity | relforcerowsecurity | relispopulated | relreplident | relispartition | relrewrite | relfrozenxid | relminmxid | relacl |    reloptions    | relpartbound 
-------+------------------+--------------+---------+-----------+----------+-------+-------------+---------------+----------+-----------+---------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------------+---------+----------+------
-----+-------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+---------------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+------------+--------------+------------+--------+------------------+--------------
 16434 | pgbench_accounts |         2200 |   16436 |         0 |       10 |     2 |       16440 |             0 |     1640 |    100000 |          1640 |             0 | t           | f           | p              | r       |        4 |      
   0 | f           | f              | f              | f              | f                   | t              | d            | f              |          0 |          514 |          1 |        | {fillfactor=100} | 
(1 row)

-bash-4.2$ pg_waldump 00000001000000000000000* | grep 16440
rmgr: Storage     len (rec/tot):     42/    42, tx:        514, lsn: 0/02EC03B0, prev 0/02EC0380, desc: CREATE base/13255/16440
rmgr: Heap2       len (rec/tot):   6515/  6515, tx:        514, lsn: 0/02EC0CC0, prev 0/02EC0C78, desc: MULTI_INSERT+INIT 61 tuples flags 0x00, blkref #0: rel 1663/13255/16440 blk 0
rmgr: Heap2       len (rec/tot):   6515/  6515, tx:        514, lsn: 0/02EC2650, prev 0/02EC0CC0, desc: MULTI_INSERT+INIT 61 tuples flags 0x00, blkref #0: rel 1663/13255/16440 blk 1
rmgr: Heap2       len (rec/tot):   6515/  6515, tx:        514, lsn: 0/02EC3FC8, prev 0/02EC2650, desc: MULTI_INSERT+INIT 61 tuples flags 0x00, blkref #0: rel 1663/13255/16440 blk 2
rmgr: Heap2       len (rec/tot):   6515/  6515, tx:        514, lsn: 0/02EC5958, prev 0/02EC3FC8, desc: MULTI_INSERT+INIT 61 tuples flags 0x00, blkref #0: rel 1663/13255/16440 blk 3
rmgr: Heap2       len (rec/tot):   6515/  6515, tx:        514, lsn: 0/02EC72E8, prev 0/02EC5958, desc: MULTI_INSERT+INIT 61 tuples flags 0x00, blkref #0: rel 1663/13255/16440 blk 4
rmgr: Heap2       len (rec/tot):   6515/  6515, tx:        514, lsn: 0/02EC8C78, prev 0/02EC72E8, desc: MULTI_INSERT+INIT 61 tuples flags 0x00, blkref #0: rel 1663/13255/16440 blk 5
rmgr: Heap2       len (rec/tot):   6515/  6515, tx:        514, lsn: 0/02ECA608, prev 0/02EC8C78, desc: MULTI_INSERT+INIT 61 tuples flags 0x00, blkref #0: rel 1663/13255/16440 blk 6
rmgr: Heap2       len (rec/tot):   6515/  6515, tx:        514, lsn: 0/02ECBF80, prev 0/02ECA608, desc: MULTI_INSERT+INIT 61 tuples flags 0x00, blkref #0: rel 1663/13255/16440 blk 7
rmgr: Heap2       len (rec/tot):   6515/  6515, tx:        514, lsn: 0/02ECD910, prev 0/02ECBF80, desc: MULTI_INSERT+INIT 61 tuples flags 0x00, blkref #0: rel 1663/13255/16440 blk 8
rmgr: Heap2       len (rec/tot):   6515/  6515, tx:        514, lsn: 0/02ECF2A0, prev 0/02ECD910, desc: MULTI_INSERT+INIT 61 tuples flags 0x00, blkref #0: rel 1663/13255/16440 blk 9
rmgr: Heap2       len (rec/tot):   6515/  6515, tx:        514, lsn: 0/02ED0C30, prev 0/02ECF2A0, desc: MULTI_INSERT+INIT 61 tuples flags 0x00, blkref #0: rel 1663/13255/16440 blk 10
<snip>
```

Bear in mind that in WAL, tables are referred to by their `relfilenode` and not by their `oid` (look for `16440` in the example)

More information about `pg_waldump` can be found [in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgwaldump.html)

Comment: thanks, your pointer on how to make sense of the `rel xxx/yyy/zzz` part definitely helped.

Comment: Isn't there a builtin option which translates those numbers to human readable output by connecting to a known server ? do I have to roll out a script of my own ?

Comment: No, you cannot automatically translate the WAL information to tables. That's what logical decoding does, but it cannot be done later.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: noted. In your answer you mention `TRUNCATE` which will make a specific oid for a table obsolete, for example. Are there other regular actions which can change the oid of a table ? or can I consider that, if I don't truncate any tables, their oid will remain stable in time ?

Comment: It doesn't change the OID, but the file. Table/index rewrite also happens during `VACUUM (FULL)`, `CLUSTER`, `REINDEX` and some `ALTER TABLE` statements.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a radically different approach to solve your problem. WAL is binary information, and the connection between WAL records and tables is tenuous: for example, if you `TRUNCATE` a table, it gets a different file, and you cannot figure out any more what table an old WAL entry belongs to.

But you can easily see how many rows get inserted, updated and deleted in each table:

```
SELECT relid::regclass, n_tup_ins, n_tup_upd, n_tup_del
FROM pg_stat_user_tables;
```

These counts are cumulative and include all activity since the last statistics reset or crash, so you would run the same query on two consecutive days (or weeks) and calculate the difference to get an idea how many data modifications each table receives. The more data modifications, the more WAL.

This is of course a very coarse estimate. For one, it will depend on the row size. You could estimate the row size with

```
SELECT schemaname, tablename, sum(avg_width) + 23 AS row_size
FROM pg_stats
GROUP BY schemaname, tablename;
```

You can factor that size into the calculation. Again, that row size is a very coarse estimate.

Comment: thanks for your input, we will start monitoring these statistics