# where can I find the documentation for the output format of pg_waldump?

Tags: postgresql, wal, postgresql-15

when asking that question : [what tables and how many rows are affected by the actions in a single wal file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77328874/what-tables-and-how-many-rows-are-affected-by-the-actions-in-a-single-wal-file)

I was directed (correctly) to using `pg_waldump` and treating the `zzz` in `rel xxx/yyy/zzz` as the `relfilenode` which identified the table (or more accurately: the relation) which was affected by an entry in wal files.

I tried reading the documentation for [`pg_waldump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/pgwaldump.html) and wasn't able to find a description of the output format.

By similarity, I was able to understand that the `xxx/yyy/zzz` in the output matched the format for the `--relation=` format (and is probably `namespace oid/database oid/relfilenod`), but I did not find on this page a sentence stating "in the output, `rel xxx/yyy/zzz` refers to ...".

For example: I don't know how to make sense of the `len (rec/tot):   2063/  2063` field.

**Question**

Where can I find a description of the output format of pg_waldump ?

Comment: this is the source code for pg_waldump: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/bin/pg_waldump/pg_waldump.c

Comment: self note: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/36a14afc076024ba48c399f2af2d4cd1b2c39348/src/bin/pg_waldump/pg_waldump.c#L546